# Unable to attach a highstock to a div

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a function like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submitbutton").on("click", function(){
        //disable the button to prevent multiple clicks
        $("#submitbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        var myname = $("#namefield").val();
        //perform the request
        var req = ocpu.rpc("output", {
          myname : myname

        }, function(output){

//I am getting undefined is not a function error
          $("#output").highstock({
        chart: {
            borderColor: '#98AFC7',
                borderRadius: 20
```

Can attached highstock to a div like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to create a Highcharts/Highstock chart, but that is not one of them.

In short you could use `.highcharts('StockChart', ...` instead of `.highstock(...`.

**Highstock stock chart**

jQuery specific:

```
$('#output').highcharts('StockChart', { 
    // options 
});
```

General:

```
new Highcharts.StockChart({ 
    chart: { 
        renderTo: 'output' 
    } 
    // rest of options 
});
```

**Highcharts regular chart**

jQuery specific:

```
$('#output').highcharts({ 
    // options 
});
```

General:

```
new Highcharts.Chart({ 
    chart: { 
        renderTo: 'output' 
    } 
    // rest of options 
});
```

I suggest reading up on the ["Getting started"](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart) guide.